# Lua - string.gmatch iterator - does it search every iteration?

Tags: performance, lua, lua-patterns

Does gmatch iterator finds all occurences immediately after it was called or does it try to find new occurence each iteration?

```
for elem in string.gmatch(s, pattern) do
    ...
end
```

It's important because it will be used a lot in my program, so if `string.gmatch` just tries to find next occurence each iteration, it will be much more friendlier to performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string.gmatch` produces an iterator which finds the next match at each iteration.